# How to keep a local value from being set when a binding fails (so inherited values will propagate)

Tags: c#, wpf

Consider the following scenario:

I want to bind the TextElement.FontWeight property to an xml attribute. The xml looks somewhat like this and has arbitrary depth.

```
<text font-weight="bold">
    bold text here
    <inlinetext>more bold text</inlinetext>
    even more bold text
</text>
```

I use hierarchical templating to display the text, no problem there, but having a Setter in the template style like:

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="{Binding XPath=@font-weight}"/>
```

sets the fontweight correctly on the first level, but overwrites the second level with null (as the binding can't find the xpath) which reverts to Fontweight normal.

I tried all sorts of things here but nothing quite seems to work.

e.g. i used a converter to return UnsetValue, which didn't work.

I'm currently trying with:

```
<Setter Property="custom:AttributeInserter.Wrapper" Value="{custom:AttributeInserter Property=TextElement.FontWeight, Binding={Binding XPath=@font-weight}}"/>
```

Codebehind:

```
public static class AttributeInserter
{
    public static AttributeInserterExtension GetWrapper(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (AttributeInserterExtension)obj.GetValue(WrapperProperty);
    }
    public static void SetWrapper(DependencyObject obj, AttributeInserterExtension value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WrapperProperty, value);
    }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Wrapper.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WrapperProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Wrapper", typeof(AttributeInserterExtension), typeof(AttributeInserter), new UIPropertyMetadata(pcc));

    static void pcc(DependencyObject o,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var n=e.NewValue as AttributeInserterExtension;
        var c = o as FrameworkElement;
        if (n == null || c==null || n.Property==null || n.Binding==null)
            return;

        var bex = c.SetBinding(n.Property, n.Binding);
        bex.UpdateTarget();
        if (bex.Status == BindingStatus.UpdateTargetError)
            c.ClearValue(n.Property);
    }

}

public class AttributeInserterExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public DependencyProperty Property { get; set; }
    public Binding Binding { get; set; }
}
```

which kinda works, but can't track changes of the property

Any ideas? Any links?

thx for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Using an attached property is the way to go.

**Simplest solution**

If you're willing to code for each inherited property (there aren't very many of them) it can be much simpler:

```
<Setter Property="my:OnlyIfSet.FontWeight" Value="{Binding XPath=@font-weight}"/>
```

with code

```
public class OnlyIfSet : DependencyObject
{
  public static FontWeight GetFontWeight(DependencyObject obj) { return (FontWeight)obj.GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
  public static void SetFontWeight(DependencyObject obj, FontWeight value) { obj.SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FontWeight", typeof(FontWeight), typeof(Object), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
      {
        if(e.NewValue!=null)
          obj.SetValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, e.NewValue);
        else
          obj.ClearValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);
      }
  });
}
```

**Generalizing for multiple properties**

Generalizing this can be done in several ways.  One is to create a generalized property registering method, but still use multiple attached properties:

```
public class OnlyIfSet
{
  static DependencyProperty CreateMap(DependencyProperty prop)
  {
    return DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      prop.Name, prop.PropertyType, typeof(OnlyIfSet), new PropertyMetadata
      {
        PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
        {
          if(e.NewValue!=null)
            obj.SetValue(prop, e.NewValue);
          else
          obj.ClearValue(prop);
        }
      });
  }

  public static FontWeight GetFontWeight(DependencyObject obj) { return (FontWeight)obj.GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
  public static void SetFontWeight(DependencyObject obj, FontWeight value) { obj.SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty =
    CreateMap(TextElement.FontWeightProperty);

  public static double GetFontSize(DependencyObject obj) { return (double)obj.GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
  public static void SetFontSize(DependencyObject obj, double value) { obj.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
    CreateMap(TextElement.FontSizeProperty);

  ...    
}
```

**Allowing arbitrary properties**

Another approach is to use two attached properties:

```
<Setter Property="my:ConditionalSetter.Property" Value="FontWeight" />
<Setter Property="my:ConditionalSetter.Value" Value="{Binding XPath=@font-weight}"/>
```

with code

```
public class ConditionalSetter : DependencyObject
{
  public string GetProperty( ... // Attached property
  public void SetProperty( ...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyProperty = ...
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = Update,
  });

  public object GetValue( ... // Attached property
  public void SetValue( ...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = ...
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = Update,
  });

  void Update(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var property = GetProperty(obj);
    var value = GetValue(obj);
    if(property==null) return;

    var prop = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(property, obj.GetType(), typeof(object)).DependencyProperty;
    if(prop==null) return;

    if(value!=null)
      obj.SetValue(prop, value);
    else
      obj.ClearValue(prop);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, will look into it tomorrow and report back

Comment: One of your key points i overlooked was "there aren't very many of [inherited properties]", that's why i'm going for your "Generalizing for multiple properties"-approach, which definately is neat. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if anyone comes across this, my final solution was this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@font-weight,Converter={converters:IsNullConverter}}" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="{Binding XPath=@font-weight}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

with IsNullConverter being a simple Valueconverter with this body:

```
return value == null;
```